# How to perform WSO2 user authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How will you authenticate a user created in WSO2? I need to check if the password entered by the user is correct before performing some function. Are there any SCIM apis for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several APIs you can use to authenticate user.

- [RemoteUserStoreManagerService](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs) (SOAP service)
- [SCIM2 API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/SCIM+2.0+REST+APIs) (you can use /scim2/Me GET method for this, though this API is not specifically design for this)